# split video and keep it running

Tags: expression-blend

any one can give me a hind how to split video (and can be played in separeat parts) ,by split here I mean to split it to 4 parts for example and each part can be running (paying)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using ffmpeg with the -ss option to seek to a point in the video and then use -vframes or -t to extract a specific number of frames or seconds, respectively.

See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html